# Placing SQL query results into one array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, curl

I have this PhP script:

```
 <?php

   $gregorianMonth = date(n);
   $gregorianDay = date(j);
   $gregorianYear = date(Y);

   $jdDate = gregoriantojd($gregorianMonth,$gregorianDay,$gregorianYear); 

   $hebrewMonthName = jdmonthname($jdDate,4);

   $hebrewDate = jdtojewish($jdDate); 

   list($hebrewMonth, $hebrewDay, $hebrewYear) = split('/',$hebrewDate);
  ?>

 <?php
   $table_name =  "candle_number";
   $data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT email FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `datehebrew` LIKE '%%$hebrewDay%%' AND `datehebrew` LIKE '%%$hebrewMonth%%' AND date_pref = \"hebrew\"");

   foreach( $data as $rs ){
     echo "
       <p>{$rs->email}</p>
        ";hat I can 
       $i++;
    }
 ?>
```

And what I was initially thinking was to use a `foreach` loop with the `CURL` Mailchimp API to send each email to my endpoint, kind of a one off.

BUT - I know that the `foreach` might not loop process and it's not very clean. I think the BETTER solution would be to have every result put into an array then send THAT array in the curl, because the MC API will accept it.

I am still kind of a novice though so this is where I am stuck. So how can I take those results from my query and put them into one string?

Comment: Adding to array is done with `[]` or `array_push`. Please, follow a manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//create blank array
$final_output = array();

foreach( $data as $rs ){

   //add data to array in next index.
   final_output[] = $rs->email;
   $i++;

}

//at this point send your data array wherever you want.
print_r($final_output);
```

If you want to convert your data to string use:

```
echo json_encode($final_output);
```

Comment: Actually I don't know why this got a down vote. Worked perfectly.

Comment: No idea who did it. But thanks. It will work perfectly.

Comment: I like the cut of your jib. Humblebrag :) Thank you very much!